# How to Dynamic Pivot multiple parquet files (same schema) in Azure Synapse

Tags: pivot, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a dataset that needs to be divided and partitioned by a key (template name), I was able to do this. I now have new parquet files that need to be pivoted by AttName. This is a dynamic set of files as the source system creates new templates, there will now be a new file. The files are Container/Template/Year/Month.

I've tried a lot of things within the same dataflow and it always fails. I've attempted to use metadata and a foreach but I keep getting lost.

Any and all help would be nice.

Comment: Did you try the Pivot activity in Dataflow? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot

Comment: @JoelCochran Yes I did. I know I'll need to use that but I'm not able to figure out how to have it loop through the directory and change the source of the pivot based on that. 
I'm using Get MetaData to get a list of files and trying to pass them into a foreach loop now. I'm not sure if that's the right way, just the only way I can think to do it.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you may need to loop over the GetMetadata and call the DataFlow once per Template.

Comment: As per my understanding you want to iterate on each file of the container and pivot every file using AttName column, am I right?

Comment: @PratikLad that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Get Meta data wild card placeholder(dataset parameter) with values like `*/*/*/*.csv` to get all files list and pass it to a ForEach with dataflow activity as discussed in comments.

Also, you can try the below alternative if you are not sure about dataflow wild card path.

This are my variable and pipeline flow.

[image]

First use a copy activity with wild card path and an additional column `$FILEPATH`. Use merge option in sink and copy this single file to a temporary location.

[image]

This will add a column for all file records paths and merges into a single file.
Then use lookup for that temporary merged file and give that to a ForEach(with `@item().filepath` to append activity to `patharray` variable) to get array of all file paths from the column.

Then to get all unique file paths array take another set variable activity with dynamic content `@union(variables('pathsarray'),variables('pathsarray'))` to `respaths` variable which will give the below result.

[image]

Give this to another ForEach activity and inside ForEach use dataflow with below source.

[image]

Create a dataflow parameter `sinkfilename` and give that to sink in dataflow.

[image]

Now, inside dataflow pass `@item()` to source dataset parameter and the below dynamic content to dataflow parameter from pipeline.

`@concat('targetfolder/',split(item(),'/')[sub(length(split(item(),'/')),1)])`

[image]

Inside dataflow, you can use pivot as transformation as per your requirement.

**This is my Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
"name": "pipeline3",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Copy data for merge",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "additionalColumns": [
                        {
                            "name": "filepath",
                            "value": "$$FILEPATH"
                        }
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFolderPath": "*/*/*",
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true,
                        "fileExtension": ".csv"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "sourcefiles",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Tempcsvfiles",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Lookup to get filepath",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Copy data for merge",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "Tempcsvfiles",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Iterate for filepath array",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup to get filepath",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Lookup to get filepath').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "pathsarray",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item().filepath",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Union array",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Iterate for filepath array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "respaths",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@union(variables('pathsarray'),variables('pathsarray'))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach2",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Union array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('respaths')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Data flow1",
                        "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataflow": {
                                "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                                "type": "DataFlowReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sinkfilename": {
                                        "value": "'@{concat('targetfolder/',split(item(),'/')[sub(length(split(item(),'/')),1)])}'",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                },
                                "datasetParameters": {
                                    "source1": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item()",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "compute": {
                                "coreCount": 8,
                                "computeType": "General"
                            },
                            "traceLevel": "Fine"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "pathsarray": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "respaths": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

**This is my Result:**

[image]